# Не применяется медиазапрос

Tags: css, css3, html5, sass

Написал разметку страницы, сделал для неё стили, начал адаптировать и медиазапросы не срабатывают. Не понимаю в чём дело, буду очень благодарен, если ответите что тут не так

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .header__menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .promo__info {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .promo__list {
        margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
    }

    .category__items {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 6fr);
    }

    .price__items {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 6fr);
    }

    .questions__items {
        flex-flow: column wrap;
    }

    .questions__item {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 488px) {
    .container {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .title {
        font-size: 32px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }

    .category__items {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 12fr);
    }

    .price__items {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 12fr);
    }

    .price__item:hover {
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }

    .questions__wrapper {
        width: 95%;
    }

    .questions__subtitle {
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
    }

    .questions__item::before {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        top: -40px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }

    .questions__item:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
    }

    .questions__name {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: meta viewport в head есть ?

Comment: and надо убрать так как условие одно

Comment: Просто media screen(){} вот таким образом

Comment: Может кеш остался. Сбросьте его

Comment: С медиазапросами все нормально, может быть, стили остаются в кеше.

Answer (score 1):

в head добавь

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```